# How would I work out the two end point positions of a rotated line?

Tags: c#, coordinates, collision, detection

I am trying to figure out the end point positions (x,y,z) of a line in 3D space using the line centre position that I already know for my collision detection. I'm finding it hard to put my specific problem into words but here's a [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHJ9m.png) I have come up with.

I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: We need more information to understand your problem. The length of the line and the angle of the line is also required - it is a vector, or 2 vectors opposing one another from the known centre point to each of the end points you are looking for. If you only have the centre point there is too little information.